# Dar permisos a un archivo al hacer un log de queries (consultas) en mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Trato de hacer un log de querys de mysql en ubuntu y hago lo siguiente (lo recomendado para mysql 5.6+, que es la versión que tengo):

```
[mysqld]
general_log = on
general_log_file=/var/log/apache2/mysql-query.log
```

en mi archivo my.cnf.

Cuando reinicio el servicio de mysql hago pruebas y los query no se almacenan en la ruta que especifiqué. El archivo tiene permisos 666 y el el owner lo dejé de la siguiente forma:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/apache2/mysql-query.log
```

Después entro a mysql desde consola y ejecuto manualmente lo que puse en mi archivo my.cnf.

```
 SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

y me marca el siguiente error:

> ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/var/log/apache2/mysql-query.log' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

¿Por qué? Se supone que ya tiene permisos el archivo. Necesito ayuda.

Comment: Hola, ¿y cómo estás ingresando a la consola de MySQL?

Comment: como usuario root: **mysql -u root -p**. Pero no creo que eso sea relevante porque el usuario no es el que escribe, el encargado es el proceso de mysqld del motor de BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví el problema basandome en esta [respuesta](https://serverfault.com/questions/351062/general-logging-wont-work-in-mysql) encontrada en ServetFault.

Parece que el problema si eran los permisos del archivo del log. A pesar de tener los permisos correctos, el usuario no tiene acceso a la ruta que le indico (desconozco por qué no puede accesar). Lo que hice fue crear el log en la carpeta de datos de mysql **/var/lib/mysql/**.

Ahora funciona correctamente en la nueva ruta especificada.